# Symfony 2.3 using checkbox form to delete row/entry in database

Tags: php, forms, symfony, checkbox

my problem is that I need a checkbox form that when ticked and submitted it deletes an entry from the database.

lets say I uploaded an image to the database using a "file type field" and is displayed somewhere in the page. so in my twig I would have a

```
<a href="{{ path('z_image_delete', {'id':aimage.id})}}" class="icon-edit" style="position:absolute;"></a>
```

in a for loop to get the id of the image, this puts an icon that if clicked, will go to the action with the route z_image_delete and will delete the image using an action with a

> remove() and flush()

is there any way to have this same functionality if I use a checkbox type field?

So instead of an icon I would have a checkbox and a submit button and if that check box was checked and submitted it would delete the image.

Thanks in advance

Comment: In the checkbox values you put the id of the image and when you submit your form in the action you checked what checkbox have been checked to get their value that corresponding to picture id and then you can delete the pictures easily

Comment: is there an isChecked function for the checkbox? I'm sorry if it's a stupid question but i'm faily new to symfony and the documentations for 2.3 suddenly disappeared from the site. @DOZ

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a [Form](http://symfony.com/doc/current/forms.html), with a checkbox for each image.

Use the image id as id for the checkbox.

If the form is submitted and valid iterate over the images to know if their checkboxes were checked or not :

```
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;

use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\CheckboxType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\SubmitType;

public function deleteImagesAction(Request $request){

    // ...

    $images = // ...

    $formBuilder = $this->createFormBuilder();

    foreach($images as $image){
        $formBuilder->add($image->getId(),CheckboxType::class,array('label'=>$image->getName(),'required'=>false));
    }

    $formBuilder->add('submit',SubmitType::class);

    $form = $formBuilder->getForm();

    $form->handleRequest($request);

    if($form->isValid()){
        $data = $form->getData();

        $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getEntityManager();

        foreach($images as $image){
            if($data[$image->getId()]){
                $em->remove($image);
            }
        }

        $em->flush();

        return $this->redirectToRoute(...);
    }

    return $this->render(...);
}
```

Comment: I'll just ask a really stupid question here so have mercy on me, but the $images is it the same as a data_class? would it have the path of the entity with the actual image?

Comment: just got it, it was the repository, my bad

Comment: I'm trying to make it work using the logic you have provided, I have problems with the for loop in the if statement because the code just accepts the form as valid but doesn't process the for loop. what happens is that it just flushes and redirects